# React too many rerenders

Tags: reactjs, geolocation, react-hooks

I know there are multiple questions concerning this error but i try to find a solution for this specific problem.

In the child component i fetch the users geolocation and return an object when the data arrives.

```
export default () => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState({
    loaded: false,
    coordinates: { lat: "", lng: "" },
  });

  const onSuccess = (location) => {
    setLocation({
      loaded: true,
      coordinates: {
        lat: location.coords.latitude,
        lng: location.coords.longitude,
      },
    });
  };

  const onError = (error) => {
    setLocation({
      loaded: true,
      error: {
        code: error.code,
        message: error.message,
      },
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!("geolocation" in navigator)) {
      onError({
        code: 0,
        message: "Geolocation not supported",
      });
    }

    navigator.geolocation
      .getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError)
  }, []);

  return location;
};
```

In my parent component i want to update my state using React hooks

```
import { LocateUser } from "../components";

export default () => {
  const [userPos, setUserPos] = useState({ lat: "", lon: "" });
  const location = LocateUser();

  if (location.loaded) {
     console.log(location.coordinates.lat);
     setUserPos({ // this creates the error
       lat: location.coordinates.lat,
       lon: location.coordinates.lng,
     });
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        { location.loaded ? JSON.stringify(location) : 'No location found' }
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

I already tried using useEffect and other workarounds but didn't find a solution to make it work.
The problem is that the the first time Child Component is loaded, the geolocation response is empty, a little later it returns the object with it's data.
What would be the solution to get the response from the Child Component and update the Parent Components state?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify the update frequency of `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError)`?

Comment: Well in the parent component you can see the print of `{ location.loaded ? JSON.stringify(location) : 'No location found' }`.
This returns a tiny fraction on 'No location found' and very soon afterwards shows the right Lat en Lon.
So when the data is there that's when `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError)` stops

Comment: And everytime the home component is rendered, that’s when the user’s location is asked via LocateUser.js

Comment: I see. My mistake for misreading.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap another `useEffect` for

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (location.loaded) {
     console.log(location.coordinates.lat);
     setUserPos({
       lat: location.coordinates.lat,
       lon: location.coordinates.lng,
     });
  }
}, [location]) // location inside dependency array of the side effect
```

so that updates to the `location` returned by `LocateUser()` which appears to be a custom hook, are "listened" and calls the side effect to update the parent component's state.

Comment: This way the error problem is gone indeed but the values in the userPos state are empty, like so "" ...

Comment: I allready tried this before making this question :) so its very strange. Do you have any idea what the cause can be? Thanks for the reply btw

Comment: I'm suspecting your `useEffect` for the `LocateUser()` custom hook is missing `onSuccess`, and `onError` in the dependency array, since the `getCurrentPosition()` call uses these 2 as callback functions. But this shouldn't be an issue on runtime as `onSuccess` and `onError` simply calls `setLocation()`, a set state function. So, can you check if other components in your app that might be causing the `too many re-renders` error. Is something else using the `location` variable? or re-using `LocateUser()`.

Comment: Also, is `getCurrentPosition` an asynchronous function? If so, there are ways to call that properly in a `useEffect`.